# If $A \cap B =\emptyset $ then $A^- \cap B^\circ =\emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A,B\subset X$ If $A \cap B =\emptyset $ then $A^- \cap B^\circ =\emptyset$ ?  We have that $A \cap B^\circ \subset A\cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cap B^\circ \subset A^- \cap B^\circ $ ...? How can I finish it. Please

Comment: What are $A^-$ and $B^\circ$?

Comment: @5xum Probably the closure and the interior, respectively of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Suzet  yes sorry. Thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way is to use the definition of closure and interior:

Suppose $A \cap B = \varnothing$.  Could $A^- \cap B^o$ be nonempty?  Suppose $x \in  A^- \cap B^o$.  Then in particular $x \in B^o$.  Therefore, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ with $U \subseteq B$.  But since $A \cap B = \varnothing$, we have $U \cap A = \varnothing$.  So: $x$ has a neighborhood disjoint from $A$, which means $x \notin A^-$.  This contradicts $x \in  A^- \cap B^o$.

Answer (score 1):

Use that $A^-$ is the *smallest* closed set that contains $A$; also $X\setminus B^\circ$ is *some* closed set that contains $A$. Hence $A^-\subseteq X\setminus B^\circ$.

Comment: Correct. Thank you